# How to use dynamic filters in SOSL queries

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I have this below 2 SOSL queries. One which is simple one and 2nd is dynamic.

I am passing the below data to this method. The 1st SOSL is returning the data, but the dyanamic SOSL is returning NULL.

IS there any issue with dynamic SOSL.

```
List<Id> i = new List<Id>();
i.add('01tD0000004maFQIAY');
List<String> params = new List<String>();
params.add('Is_Child__c = true');
params.add('Type_Of_Location__c = \'Country\'');
List<LookupSearchResult> r = TestClass.searchCountries('Bangalore',i,'Geography__c',params);
```

Method

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<LookupSearchResult> searchCountries(String searchTerm, List<String> selectedIds, String objectName, List<String> params) {
        system.debug('searchTerm' + searchTerm);
        // Prepare query paramters
        searchTerm += '*';

        // Execute search query
        List<List<SObject>> searchResults = [FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
                                             Geography__c (Id, Name WHERE Name NOT IN :selectedIds)
                                             LIMIT :MAX_RESULTS];
        if(params.size() > 0) {
            String query;
            query = 'Id,Name ';
            query += ' WHERE Name NOT IN :selectedIds AND' + ' ('+ params[0] +' OR ' +params[1] + ')';            
            query = 'FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + '\'  IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ' + objectName + '(' + query + ')';
            system.debug('query' + query);
            List<List<sObject>> tempVal = search.query(query);
            system.debug('tempVal' + tempVal);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you provide the QUERY generated by system.debug ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run the SOSL query successfully with different fields and returned records with the dynamic query. I think what is happening is that the additional filtering terms on the second query that are not present on the first, are in fact restricting the results:

```
params.add('Is_Child__c = true');
params.add('Type_Of_Location__c = \'Country\'');
```

Add the additional filters to the first query and you will see no results there either. Hopefully this helps.